# сборка html сайта, содержащего большое количество javascript скриптов

Tags: javascript, html, сборка, оптимизация-сайтов, assembly

Приветствую!

Создал сайт, который кроме css, изображений и прочих ресурсов содержит большое количество javascript скриптов, как внешних (jQuery), так и внутренних (собственные библиотеки и функции текущего сайта).

Хочу сформировать сайт так, чтобы он представлял собой единую страницу, не содержащую (или содержащий по минимуму) вызов скриптов, чтобы скрипты находились уже внутри страницы.

Т.е. осуществить этакую сборку сайта.

Подскажите, есть ли какие-то утилиты для такой операции и вообще стоит ли делать такую сборку сайта? Является ли это "хорошим тоном"?

Для отладки, понятное дело, используется сайт (проект) без каких либо изменений.

Comment: Можешь конечно использовать сервисы для combine+min, например: https://www.ofoct.com/combine-js-files , но лучше webpack: https://webpack.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты будешь запихивать весь js из внешних и внутренних библиотек в тег script, то сайт превратится в кашу. Лучший вариант - использовать webpack, установив все внешние библиотеки с помощью npm и импортировав их в один js файл с помощью import из современного EcmaScript и выход подключить стандартным образом в HTML. Совет: Если хочешь минимальный размер файла, поищи webpack production mode и webpack and uglify js, но pruduction лучше всего использовать, когда все готово, иначе рискуешь потерять нужные ошибки. В общем, поищи webpack, всё сразу станет ясно.

Comment: Еще один совет: постарайся отказаться от jquery. Современный js может все то же, что и jquery и при этом работает нативно в браузере. Например, для $('#element').onclick() есть addEventListener. Да, плагинов для jquery может недоставать, но это мотивация сделать велосипед и потренироваться в программировании.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что описанные способы подразумевают определенные библиотеки на стороне клиента?

Про клиентскую сторону я ничего сказать не могу, максимум, что самое худшее, что может случиться - это IE10 у пользователя.

Для npm, import и т.п. нужно (я этим не занимался, так что наверное ошибаюсь) что-то установленное и у клиента-пользователя или это не так?

Comment: @Zhihar npm - это сборник либ, подобный тому же pip у Python. Он просто снабжает тебя необходимым кодом, который ты потом используешь в импортах. Импорты используются только в webpack'е, так как это экспериментальная функция: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import . А что касается старых версий браузеров, то не думаю, что над ними стоит заморачиваться, ибо они все умирают, и это правильно.